# How to output random word using input word?

Tags: java

I want from user to input a word and then it returns a random word using the input characters, does it need a for-loop?
I kinda stuck here...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");

    String temp = input.nextLine();
    char[] myWord = temp.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<myWord.length;i++) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us sample input and output.  @Hovercraft yes I suspect this as well.

Comment: [Similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+shuffle+char+array+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You can Generate random words using permutation. But those all won't be grammatically correct.